# Does the 'xunit' tag need cleaning?

Tags: discussion, tags

'xunit' can have two meanings:

- [the series of xUnit frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit)
- [xUnit.net, a specific .net testing framework](http://xunit.codeplex.com/)

The [xunit.net](/questions/tagged/xunit.net) tag is all right, but I think the [xunit](/questions/tagged/xunit) tag needs cleaning:

[xunit](/questions/tagged/xunit)'s [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xunit/info) says that it's about xUnit.net as well.
But it doesn't have questions about xUnit.net only - there are also questions about Java, Jenkins etc.

I guess the best solution would be to move all the xUnit.net related questions to the [xunit.net](/questions/tagged/xunit.net) tag and change the tag wiki of [xunit](/questions/tagged/xunit) and make clear that it's about the xUnit series.

**Possible problem:**
I've often seen people refer to xUnit.net as only 'xUnit' (without .net), so probably some people won't recognize the difference and will still use the [xunit](/questions/tagged/xunit) tag for xUnit.net related stuff in the future.

1. Any ideas?
2. Do you even agree with me?
   My personal opinion is that current state is confusing (I was looking for xUnit.net, found the [xunit](/questions/tagged/xunit) tag and there was lots of stuff that was not what I needed).
   On the other hand, you could say that xUnit.net also belongs to the series of xUnit frameworks, so there's nothing wrong with it being in the [xunit](/questions/tagged/xunit) tag as well.